# Reading a json file with multiple "data" arrays

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, csv

I have a json file and I need to convert it into a csv file. When I try to read it in using Python3, I end up getting value errors because it is formatted into multiple arrays. What I mean is that usually a json file will only have one "data" array that makes up the whole file, but I have multiple "data" and "error" arrays in the same file, creating breaks in the json formatting. Here's an example of this kind of "break":

```
        {
        "detail": "Could not find user with ids: [99].",
        "parameter": "ids",
        "resource_id": "99",
        "resource_type": "user",
        "title": "Not Found Error",
        "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/resource-not-found",
        "value": "99"
    }
]
}{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": "2006-04-13T01:08:55.000Z",
```

Essentially what's happening is the above is an array of "error", which are users that Twitter was not able to find, and then another array below with successfully grabbed users, or "data." 
Is there a way to split this up into multiple json files at the different data and error arrays so I can read them in with json.load(), or is there another package of some sort that will allow me to read such a file? I've tried using pandas but it returns the same error as json.load().

Edit: It appears I have put together multiple json files into one file and need to split them up. Also, this is the error I get from json decoder.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1601 column 2 (char 59799)
```

The line it's referring to is a break between json files.

Comment: How did you get the json file? If you got it using code, edit the code to save two json files or add the code to your question.

Comment: @LeoWard Yes, I got it using code, but unfortunately the code takes a few days to run fully so it would be a pain to redo everything.

Answer (score 0):

This will read from the start to line 10 and write it into another file:

```
with open("in.json", "r") as f:

    with open("out.json", "w") as f1:
        for i in range(10):
            f1.write(next(f))
```

This will read from line 11 to the end of the file and write it into another file:

```
with open("in.json", "r") as f:

    for i in range(10):
        next(f)

    with open("out.json", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

Comment: The second is correct. It's multiple json files in one. I guess that's the correct way to describe it. So the json.load doesn't work because it tries to read it as one file, I guess.

Comment: And the file is 1 GB large with over 1.5 million lines, so I can't really go back and manually split them up.

Comment: I updated my answer. I've only tested it with a small json file.